Running kubectl as root
When running kubectl as root I get this error:
Couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:38805/api? timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:38805: connect: connection refused
But when I run it from user it runs okay
When I run kubectl config view as root and as user I get 2 different outputs.

Above is correct but you want to add this kube config to for root use below command to add and after that you will be able to use kubect command directly with root user. add it in linux env by export command or in windows by set-
export KUBECONFIG=path/to/kubeconfig.yaml


kubectl will look for the default kubeconfig file $HOME/.kube/config.
Remember that $HOME is the home directory of the user running the command. If you are running kubectl as root, your root user needs to have that file at /root/.kube/config correctly defined.
Overall, you do not need to create any files in your root's home directory. You can simply force kubectl to use a fixed kubeconfig file:
sudo kubectl --kubeconfig=/home/myuser/.kube/config ...

If you already have an environment variable KUBECONFIG that points to your kubeconfig file, you can also use sudo -E to inherit the current user's environment while using sudo.
sudo -E kubectl ...

